# Get the mean of two DataFrames with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames, which I am trying to make a single containing the mean of the two. Each has missing values.

If there were not missing values I could use (df1 + df2)/2.

I would like to take the mean of those that have both data points, while returning 'NaN' as the 'mean' for the points that are missing data.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta'], 'Var1': [15,'NaN', 17, 18], 'Var2': [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 1.5], 'Var3': [1, 0, 0, 1]})   

df1 = df1.set_index('ID')

        Var1  Var2  Var3
ID                      
Alpha     15   1.0     1
Bravo    NaN   1.5     0
Charlie   17   2.0     0
Delta     18   1.5     1
```

_

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta'], 'Var1': [20, 15, 17, 20], 'Var2': [1.2,'NaN', 3.0, 1.0], 'Var3': [0, 0, 1, 1]})

df2=df2.set_index('ID')

         Var1 Var2  Var3
ID                      
Alpha      20  1.2     0
Bravo      15  NaN     0
Charlie    17    3     1
Delta      20    1     1
```

_

The resulting DataFrame should be:

```
         Var1   Var2  Var3
ID                      
Alpha      17.5  1.10  0.5
Bravo      NaN   NaN   0.0
Charlie    17.0  2.50  0.5
Delta      19.0  1.25  1.0
```

So, in simple terms, my question is how can I do (df1 + df2)/2 while ignoring the points that have NaN's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do exactly that, `(df1 + df2) / 2`.

Your real problem here is that the NaN-containing columns in your DataFrames are of `object` dtype, not floating datatypes. Fix that, and the above method works. Ideally fix that by having `np.nan` in your inputs, or alternatively force the column dtypes to numeric later.

```
df1 = df1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `columns` `type` for `var1` in both `df1` and `df2` is object , that is because of the original data is  `[1.2,'NaN', 3.0, 1.0]` which is mixed type also 'NaN' is not `np.NaN` .

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta'], 'Var1': [15,np.NaN, 17, 18], 'Var2': [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 1.5], 'Var3': [1, 0, 0, 1]})   
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta'], 'Var1': [20, 15, 17, 20], 'Var2': [1.2,np.NaN, 3.0, 1.0], 'Var3': [0, 0, 1, 1]})
df2=df2.set_index('ID')
df1.add(df2)/2
Out[109]: 
         Var1  Var2  Var3
ID                       
Alpha    17.5  1.10   0.5
Bravo     NaN   NaN   0.0
Charlie  17.0  2.50   0.5
Delta    19.0  1.25   1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use NumPy to calculate the mean of an array of arrays.

```
arr = np.array([df1.replace('NaN', np.nan).values,
                df2.replace('NaN', np.nan).values])

res = pd.DataFrame(arr.mean(0), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)

print(res)

         Var1  Var2  Var3
ID                       
Alpha    17.5  1.10   0.5
Bravo     NaN   NaN   0.0
Charlie  17.0  2.50   0.5
Delta    19.0  1.25   1.0
```

**Explanation**

This solution requires the following steps:

1. Convert strings `'NaN'` to `np.nan`.
2. Combine 2 arrays into an array of arrays.
3. Compute mean over `axis=0`.
4. Construct dataframe, feeding index and columns from inputs.